# Question on matrices and complex eigenvalues 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ $\in$ $\Bbb R^{n, n}$, $AA^T$ $=$ $A^TA$. Then all complex eigenvalues of $A$ are real.

Is this true or false? How do I show with a short justification?

Please can someone lend a hand?

Comment: All complex eigenvalues are real?  What does that mean?

Comment: @DougM Real numbers are in the complex field, but not every complex number is real. The OP is referring to the possibly complex eigenvalues.

Comment: @egreg why wouldn't you say "If $A^TA = AA^T$ then $A$ has real eigenvalues."?

Comment: @DougM Possibly the OP's instructor uses that terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition means that $A$ is *normal*. A normal real matrix has only real eigenvalues if and only if it is symmetric. But antisymmetric and orthogonal matrices are normal.

Answer (score 3):

$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues in your case are just a positive real number and I think the eigenvalues are equal for both cases $AA^{T}$ $A^{T}A$. I mean if A is a unitary matrix.